# How do you disconnect from a MySQL server in VSCode?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am connected simultaneously to both a MySQL server (connection is visible at bottom left in VSCode), and an SQL Server (connection is visible at the bottom right of VSCode).

I am creating tables for the SQL Server but the tables are being created in MySQL Server not SQL Server. I want to disconnect VSCode from the MySQL Server without shutting MySQL. I still want MySQL running. But I want the commands in VSCode to be performed in SQL Server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no disconnect which unless I'm missing something, is a huge oversight. I cannot have both VSCode extensions running at the same time. Am I the only one who has attempted to use two different flavours of SQL at the same time in VSCode?

I have to disable the **viscode-database** extension while I am using the **SQL Server (mssql)** extension.

Even if I stop the MySQL Database in XAMPP for example, VSCode will still try to use the MySQL Server which then just gives errors since I have stopped the MySQL Server.